# What does Fey Origin do?

Tags: dnd-4e, feywild

Both the Eladrin and Wilden have Fey Origin, which means that the characters ancestors were native to the Feywild, so the character is considered a fey creature for the purpose of effects that relate to creature origin.

What are these effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are items that have powers and properties that look for fey origin:

- Cold Iron Bracers grant a defense bonus against fey creature's attacks.
- Cold Iron Weapons' immobilization daily power damages fey creatures.
- Fey Slaughter Weapons deal extra critical damage against fey creatures.

I can't think of any feats that require "fey" but I could imagine such.

I can't think of any monsters that have powers (or class powers) that look for fey, but again I could imagine such.

Comment: So its a racial ability that is purely negative.

Comment: There are two epic destinies (Feyliege and Winter Sovereign) that require fey origin. In LFR adventures, it's not uncommon to see situations where being of fey origin is a benefit (diplomatically, usually) or a hinderance.

Answer (score 5):

Mechanically these effects are (so far) defined as above, but consider the LFR example Bryant is using: 'the purpose of effects that relate to creature origin.' is **a design space that is completely open to the DM.**

"Fey" could be used as a handle for providing a bonus or access on adventures or campaign details.  Since AD&D, I've written scores of dungeons with feature-rooms or NPCs or items that say "those with elven blood may get a bonus to decipher these writings.." or "only those with orcish blood may approach the altar.."- if you have some fey and some non-fey in the group and want to create kind of a flavorful area (for example, a Feywild passage that effects characters differently).. this is a good way to do it.

These origins (not just fey, but living construct (warforged), undead (revenant and dhampyr), immortal (deva), goblinoid, etc..make great handles for things.

Comment: The one LFR example I can think of was the pit trap in the feywild temple in AGLA1-1 where fey creatures can cross but non fey get dumped into the pit with the ant swarm.

Comment: Oh, man.  That ant swarm.  It nearly murdered us all.